# Modify Object Access properties via C#

Tags: c#, .net, events

After viewing my Security Event logs on Server 2003 I have noticed that an event is logged with a failure audit.  The category is Object Access, with the following Accesses being required:

> READ_CONTROL
>   SYNCHRONIZE
>   ReadData (or ListDirectory)
>   WriteData (or AddFile)
>   AppendData (or AddSubDirectory or CreatePipeInstance)

I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to modify these properties proggramatically.  These failures are generated by postgres and tomcat executables.

***EDIT***

```
protected FileSystemRights[] AppendFileSystemRights()  
        {  
            return new FileSystemRights[]   
              {  
                  FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
                  FileSystemRights.WriteAttributes,
                  FileSystemRights.Synchronize,  
                  FileSystemRights.ReadAttributes,
                  FileSystemRights.ReadData  
              };  
          }

public void ApplySystemRight(string fileName, FileSystemRights[] rights)  
        {  
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))  
            {  
                return;  
            }  

            if (rights == null || rights.Length <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ATTEMPTING TO OPEN THE FOLLOWING FILE: {0}", fileName);
                fileSec = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);

                for (int i = 0; i < rights.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ATTEMPTING TO ADD THE FOLLOWING ACCESS RULE: {0} TO {1}", rights[i], fileName);
                    fileSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(user,
                        rights[i], AccessControlType.Allow));
                }

                Console.WriteLine("ATTEMPTING TO SET THE PRECEDING ACCESS RULES: TO {0}", fileName);
                File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fileSec);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CAUGHT THE FOLLOWING EXCEPTION: {0}  \n WHILE PROCESSING: {1}", uae.Message, fileName);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CAUGHT THE FOLLOWING EXCEPTION: {0}  \n WHILE PROCESSING: {1}", ane.Message, fileName);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ae)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CAUGHT THE FOLLOWING EXCEPTION: {0}  \n WHILE PROCESSING: {1}", ae.Message, fileName);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do you have information on what object it is that access is denied upon?

Comment: Ronald Tomcat6.exe and psql.exe

Comment: But I do not suppose these are the files that cannot be accessed? These are probably the processes that can not access a certain file (or files). You need to find out what files can not be accessed by either tomcat6.exe or psql.exe.

Comment: @Ronald wildenberg its actually just pointing directly to those executables

Comment: Yes but are these the files that can not be accessed? In that case why don't you simply set the access control properties for these files and see if it works?

Comment: You can't manually set SYNCHRONIZE, at least I haven't seen how its possible.  Appreciate the help

Comment: According to the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights.aspx), SYNCHRONIZE is set automatically.

Comment: Hmm perplexing that it logs a failure on that permission

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you run Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) while running the process that is causing the audit failure.  This should tell you the specific resource that the process is trying to access.  With this information you will be able to set the resource permissions to allow the requested access.

Answer (score 1):

This will produce a runtime error in the app that tries to access the operating system resource.  Windows error 5, ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.  If you don't get any diagnostic in the app's log file, an event in the Application event log or an explicit managed exception that tells you what went wrong then you'll be looking for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that didn't really answer the question

Comment: These apps use thousands of securable objects.  Surely you didn't expect me to tell you which one it was.  Again, if the app doesn't log this, you can only use something like SysInternals' ProcMon to see the error.  You'll drown in the haystack of data.

Comment: Correct I do not anticipate you to list all the potential security objects it could be that is why I gave a concise and finite list based on a process.

Comment: There's a list?  Where?  What's in your question are just the access rights that were requested for *one* securable object.

Comment: passant yes its that block of text in gray.  Correct that its one object as that is the object that's filling my log.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`FileSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity.aspx) class to modify access control properties programmatically. But of course you first have to find out for which file or directory these properties should be modified.